# Show that the series $∑_{m=q+2}^{∞}v_{m}r^{(q+1)²-m²}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $r>4$ be a positive integer. Let $0<v_{m}<r^{m},m≥3$ be an increasing and divergent sequence. Let $q≥3$.

My **question** is: Show that the series $$∑_{m=q+2}^{∞}v_{m}r^{(q+1)²-m²}$$ is convergent. I am not able to find the good idea.

Comment: note that the part with $r$ decays $e^{-m^2 \log r}$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ this should kill the divergency of most $v_m$,'s :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(q+1)^2$ will be neglected as it is unimportant for the convergence.
Via root test we have 
$$\sqrt[m]{\frac{p_m}{r^{m^2}}} \leq \sqrt[m]{\frac{r^m}{r^{m^2}}} \leq \frac{1}{4}$$ for all $m$ large enough
as $r\geq 4$

Comment: @ Dominic Michaelis: and the series is bounded for all $q≥3$.